# Laravel Passport Api

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

> BadMethodCallException: Method Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard::attempt does not exist. in file C:\xampp\htdocs\test\passportapi\laravel-backend-api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 112
> auth()->guard('api')->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password'])))

This is supported passport or not,
because this error shows at my end.
How to solve this?

```
config->auth.php `page`

        'company' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'company_users', // Use the appropriate provider
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport', // set this to passport
            'provider' => 'company_users',
            'hash' => false,
        ]
 if (Auth::guard('api')->attempt($request->only(['email', 'password']))) {
           $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
            $token = $logUser->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
```

Its a not working

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel `passport`(`TokenGuard`) doesn't have the `attempt()` method. It uses the `OAuth2` token, not the `session`.**

---

As you shared, you create your token like this.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) { // web login
        $user = auth()->user();
        $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['token' => $token], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
}
```

Then in the config

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users', // **** make sure this is correct(main user model should be here.) you're using `company_users` make sure it's the main user table which uses web login
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

And finally, in your request, if you pass the `Authorization` header with the `Bearer`, this will work.

> Make sure your model (in mine `users` as per your code `company_users`) has a ***trait called `HasApiTokens`***

Comment: No,  users table  is deferent table and  company_users table is a deferent table .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `attempt` is a method of `SessionGuard` but not `TokenGuard`.

If you want to authenticate a user before creating a token for them use the `web` guard.